# ipsec.py CANT FIND THE attribute IPPROTO_ESP and socket.IPPROTO_AH

Tags: python, sockets, scapy, ipsec

I install the module scapy for python 2.6 and when I import this module I get this warning:

> WARNING: can't import layer ipsec: 'module' object has no attribute 'IPPROTO_AH'

I looked in the socket attributes and i didnt find the 'IPPROTO_AH' attribute 
In addition, i tried to edit the module ipsec.py and find way to replace IPPROTO_AH with something else but then i got WARNING WITH IPPROTO_ESP !

I tried edit lines in ipsec.py such as:

```
    overload_fields = {
    IP: {'proto': IPTest},
    IPv6: {'nh': IPTest},
    IPv6ExtHdrHopByHop: {'nh': socket.IPPROTO_AH},
    IPv6ExtHdrDestOpt: {'nh': socket.IPPROTO_AH},
    IPv6ExtHdrRouting: {'nh': socket.IPPROTO_AH},}

bind_layers(IP, AH, proto=socket.IPPROTO_AH)
bind_layers(IPv6, AH, nh=socket.IPPROTO_AH)
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: Why did you added `IPPROTO_AH` from `socket` if `socket` doesn't have it? Also what is the platform/OS that you run python on?

Comment: i didnt add this . i got this module when I installed the scapy module and I didnt write any code there . My platform is windows 7.

Comment: Ok i did some more digging, i have a python2.4.4 version and `socket.IPPROTO_ESP` is 50 while `socket.IPPROTO_AH` is 51. I also checked python3.4.3, but it doesn't have them.

Comment: wow man Thanks !!
I will try to replace this attribute  with their value .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I have it... it's not a clean solution, but it will do the trick. I've seen it in other *ScaPy* files...
All you need to do is edit *ipsec.py*, look for the line `import socket`, and **just under it**, add these conditionals:

```py
if not hasattr(socket, "IPPROTO_ESP"):
    socket.IPPROTO_ESP = 50
if not hasattr(socket, "IPPROTO_AH"):
    socket.IPPROTO_AH = 51
```

Reference: [[IETF.DataTracker]: (RFC 2292) Advanced Sockets API for IPv6 - IPv6 Next Header Values](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2292#section-2.1.1).
In *Ubuntu*, their definitions can typically be found in */usr/include/netinet/in.h* (or */usr/include/linux/in.h*).

As I mentioned in one of the comments, I tested using *Python 2.7.10* on a variety of *OS*es (*Linux*es, *Sol*, *AIX*, *HP-UX*, *OSX*) and the values seem to be consistent.
On *Win*, they don't exist. Seems like *MS* removed them from *WinSock2.h* between (*VStudio*) *v2005* and *v2010*, but they **are back** (same values) since *v2012* (*ws2def.h* - for *XP* and above).

In *Python 3(.8)*, they seem to be present (checked on *Nix* (*Ubuntu*) and *Win*).

Comment: lol I rewrite all this module .. and this works (replace all the "socket.IPPROTO_AH" and "socket.IPPROTO_ESP" with their value)!! 
Thank you !!

Comment: I'd still recommend to check first if `socket` has them and if not then define them instead of replacing their occurrences with their values, because if you would like to run the code with another python installed on another machine with a different Windows version where those constant might have different values (although this wouldn't be very likely) the code won't work.

Comment: I also did a test using Python2.7.10 on a variety of OSes (Linux, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, OSX) and the values seem to be consistent, while on Win they don't exist. Seems like MS removed them from `WinSock2.h` between (VStudio) 2k5 and 2k10.